# Setup Automapper member mapping dynamically from a list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this source class:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

And this destination class (same class, but with properties in another language)

```
public class MiaClasse 
{
    public string Nominativo { get; set; } //Name
    public int Altezza { get; set; } //Height
}
```

And I already have (from an old project) a `Dictionary<string, string>()` with all the mapped properties, like

```
<Name, Nominativo>
<Height, Altezza>
```

How can I setup AutoMapper properties mapping iterating the dictionary?

Something like (pseudo code):

```
map = CreateMap<MyClass, MiaClasse>()

foreach (var m in alreadyExistingDictionary)  
{
    map.ForMember(m.Value, o => o.MapFrom(m.Key))
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Create a code generator that create the mapping code from your input dictionary, save and use that code. Don't forget to delete the dictionary afterwards to get rid of the old stuff when you are now in a new world.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did focus too hard on some Automapper hidden function to solve this problem.
It was really easy to solve using C#. I did like this:

```
map = CreateMap<MyClass, MiaClasse>()
foreach (var m in alreadyExistingDictionary)  
{
    var sourceMember = GetExpressionForProperty<TSource>(m.Key);
    var destMember = GetExpressionForProperty<TDestination>(m.Value);
    map.ForMember(destMember, o => o.MapFrom(sourceMember))
}
```

I had to create a function to easily get the expression for a member, like this one:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetExpressionForProperty<T>(string name)
{
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var p = Expression.Property(x, name);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(p, typeof(object)), x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with dictionaries:

```
var englishDictionary = mapper.Map<Dictionary<string, object>>(myClass);
var italianDictionary = Translate(englishDictionary);
var miaClasse = mapper.Map<MiaClasse>(italianDictionary);
```

See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Your idea works too, but there's no need for expressions, you just need the string based overload:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/104a192407858fe3a54a8a937ca95a34fd7c6959/src/UnitTests/ReverseMapping.cs#L663

I expect your way is a lot more efficient, as it relies on the generated code for that map.